# Алгоритм получения случайной последовательности из латинских букв и цифр

Tags: случайные-числа

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Личный сайт студента Geekbrains</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">


     function readInt() {
        var number = document.getElementById('useranswer').value;  // izvlekaet znachenie textovoqo polya
        return parseInt(number);
    }

    function hide(id) {
        document.getElementById('id').style.display = "none";
    }

    function password() {

        var result = "";
        while (result.length < readInt()) {
            result += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2); // predstavlaet stroku v sisteme schisleniya s osnovaniem 36,otsekaya 2 elementa v nachale stroki
        }

        hide('useranswer');
        hide("button");
        return result.substring(0, readInt());


    }

    function write(text) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = text; // zamenaet text po id
    }
    var n = password();

    write("Ваш пароль:" + password());
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="index.php">Main</a>
        <a href="guess.html">Guessing game</a>
        <a href="Puzzle.php">Puzzle game</a>
        <a href=#>Генератор случайных паролей</a>
    </div>
    <h1 align="center">Generator sluchaynix paroley</h1>
    <div class="box">
        <p id="info">Введите длину пароля:</p>
        <input type="text" id='useranswer'><br>
        <input type="button" value="Ввод" onclick="password()" id="button">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <a href=#>Main</a>
        <a href=#>Guessing game</a>
        <a href=#>Puzzle game</a>
        <a href=#>Generator sluchaynix paroley</a>
        <p align="center">Copyright &copy;
            <?php echo date("Y")?> Shahin Karim</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>`
```

друзья! Каков алгоритм для получения случайной последовательности из латинских букв и цифр.Решаю задание на JavaScript.Есть поле,ввожу туда длину последовательности и при нажатии на кнопку должна отобразиться случайная последовательность из латинских букв и цифр.Как отобразить случайную последовательность цифр я знаю,а вот последовательность из латинских букв + цифр,к сожалению нет.Не поможите с этим? Буду очень благодарен. Написал код.Выдаёт ошибки: Cannot read property 'value' of null и Cannot read property 'style' of null.Что делать? Как быть?

Comment: например использовать массив латинских букв array = [a, b, c, d, e...]? генерируете случайное число, пусть будет i = 3 (порядковый номер в вашем массиве), и заполняете в цикле i + array[i], в итоге 3d. Вариантов много, ограниченны лишь вашей фантазией и возможностями

Comment: а мне нужно все латинские буквы,а не определённое их количество.А все буквы вписать в массив немножко не разумно на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1):

Вот неплохой способ:

```js
function randomString(n){
  let result = ''
  while (result.length < n)
    result += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  return result.substring(0, n)  
}

console.log(randomString(10))
console.log(randomString(20))
console.log(randomString(30))
```

Comment: почему переменная "result" объявлена с помощью let ,а не Var??? и что делают "toString' и "substring" в данном коде?(какую функцию выполняют)?? Спасибо)

Comment: `toString(36)` приводит число к системе счисления с основанием 36 это `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString , `Math.random()` возвращает число от 0 до 1 при привидении его к этой системе счисления получается что-то вроде `0.7dhe6j3`, вот substring отрезает `0.`

Comment: про let или var - тут это без особой разницы

Comment: а в конце просто return result нельзя написать? без .substring(0,n)?

Comment: @shahin длина будет больше, попробуйте, за одну итерацию не 1 символ добавляется

Comment: когда используем substring отсчёт строки начинается с 0,как в массивах,или с 1?

Comment: Тут есть потенциальная проблема в том, что не все символы равновероятны. Например в `randomString(100000000)` "0" встречается примерно 2520000 раз, а "h" - 2860000 раз.

Comment: например, var n = "stack", n.substring(0,3) вернёт "sta",не так ли? т.е. мы начинаем считать элементы строки с 0?

Comment: @Yaant так точно, но никаких требований к распределению вероятностей не предоставлялось

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Поэтому я и сказал "потенциальная" :)

Comment: написал код выше,посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Извращенный способ, с магическими числами:

```js
function getString(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill().map(getChar).join('');
}

function getChar() {
  let rnd = 48 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 36);
  rnd += (rnd > 57 ? 7 : 0);
  let char = String.fromCharCode(rnd);
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? char.toLowerCase() : char;
};

console.log(getString(5));
console.log(getString(10));
console.log(getString(15));
```